# Erro: Minha matriz não imprime a ultima linha e as vezes imprime apenas metade

Tags: c, dev-c++

Ja fiz de varias formas diferentes...

```
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        for(j=0; j<=3; j++){
            O[i][j] = (3*M[i][j]) - (5*N[i][j]);
          printf("  %3d  ",O[i][j]);      
        }
      printf("\n");
    }
```

Porém a matriz não imprime ou imprime incompleta se não o resultado da última linha sai com valores aleatórios.

Segue abaixo o código completo:

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int M[2][3], N[2][3], O[2][3], i,j;

void matriz (int matriz[][3], char name[1]){ //function para pedir o usuario o valor da matriz M e N
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        for(j=0; j<=3; j++){
            printf("Matriz %s: Linha [%d] Coluna [%d]: ",name,i+1,j+1); 
            scanf("%d",&matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void printMatriz (int matriz[][3], char name[1]){ //imprensão das matrizes M e N apenas para comparação dos resultados
    printf("\n\n  _______ Matriz %s _______\n",name);
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        for(j=0; j<=3; j++){
            printf("  %3d  ",matriz[i][j]);     
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

main(){
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    
    printf("Forneça os valores das Matrizes abaixo\n\n");
    
    matriz(M,"M"); //chamada da function para matriz M e abaixo N
    matriz(N,"N");
    
    printMatriz(M,"M"); //impressão das matrizes para comparar com o resultado
    printMatriz(N,"N");

    //imprimir na tela a matriz O = 3*M - 5*N
    printf("\n\n __ Matriz O = 3*M - 5*N __\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
        for(j=0; j<=3; j++){
            O[i][j] = (3*M[i][j]) - (5*N[i][j]);
//          printf("  %3d  ",O[i][j]);      
        }
//      printf("\n");
    }[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
    printMatriz(O,"O");
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CztMk.png
````

Comment: Note que sua declaração `char name[1]` é o mesmo que `char name`, isto é ocupa 1 byte. Veja que na chamada da função, por ex. em `matriz(M,"M");`, o parâmetro "M" é uma string de 1 posição e portanto ocupa 2 bytes, o caractere seguido do caractere terminador '\0' e portanto você está invadindo área de memória não devidamente alocada. Ou declare `char name[2]` e continue utilizando "M" ou declare `char name` e passe a utilizar 'M'. Nos printf troque o %s por %c.

Comment: Fiz exatamente essas mudanças e imprimiu tudo uma vez. 
Porem, a matriz O na posição [1][3], [2][1] a [2][3] saíram erradas. Executei o program de novo e parou de imprimir a matriz O. Não entendo porque isso acontece. Executei de novo usando números diferentes sempre e nada.
O mesmo procedimento imprime a matriz M e N, mas não imprime a O. 
O que esta errado? Seria o calculo da matriz O? Eu uso o mesmo sistema de repetição.
` printf("\n\n __ Matriz O = 3*M - 5*N __");
 for(i=0; i<=2; i++){
  for(j=0; j<=3; j++){
   O[i][j] = (3*M[i][j]) - (5*N[i][j]); 
  }
 }
 printMatriz(O,'O');
`

Comment: Seus comandos `for` estão considerando uma posição a mais. Troque o `<=` por `<`. Para um array x[n] o índice varia de 0 a n-1.

Comment: Eu não estou conseguindo compreender.
A matriz tem que ter 3 linhas e 4 colunas `matriz[2][3]` se eu substituir `<=` por `<` a repetição `for` vai de `0 a 1` e depois de `0 a 2`. Se eu coloco `for(i=0;<3;i++){for(j=0;j<4;J++){}}` para imprimir a matriz 3 * 4 continua o mesmo problema.
A matriz O na posição `[1][3], [2][1] a [2][3]`, saem o valor `0,1, 2, 1, 0`.
Isso significa alguma coisa, esse erro é sempre igual.

Comment: Eu coloquei as `matriz[3][4]` todos os `for(i=0;<3;i++){for(j=0;j<4;J++)` e foi. Imprimiu 3 linhas e 4 colunas. Porém a matriz não começa a contar do 0? Desse jeito não está errado? Se alguém puder esclarecer agradeço.

Comment: Você está confundindo o tamanho do array com a variação do índice, o índice parte de 0. Ex. quando você declara `int x[4];` o array x tem 4 elementos com os índices variando de 0 a 3.